# Does Exchange support disposable e-mail addresses?

Tags: email, exchange

Sometimes it is useful to have e-mail address like `foo-randomnumber@example.org`, where `randomnumber` identifies the conversation between a robot such as a mailing list server and a user. Is this possible with Microsoft Exchange?

Comment: The correct term is "DEA", or Disposable Email Address. A wildcard email address is `*@example.com`

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia article on Disposable Email Addresses. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disposable_email_address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is now available on Office 365 Exchange!

Exchange admins will have to enable this manually on their server. This can be done through Powershell using the following command:

```
Set-OrganizationConfig -AllowPlusAddressInRecipients $true
```

For instructions on how to use Powershell, you can find out more here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps

The setting may not instantly take effect so please expect a delay before you can start using plus addresses.

We're still waiting documentation on this feature and from feedback I've seen, it doesn't work for everyone currently.

Answer (score 4):

Out of the box no.

You could develop an event sink that does the routing for you... [This might get you started](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=324021).

Comment: Fortunately or unfortunately (depending on your perspective) event sinks have been deprecated in exchange 2010.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa579182%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

While the short answer is no, when the need arises and I don't wish to use one of the many web based providers of disposable email addresses I simply create one, use it and delete it when done.

Comment: This question is about e-mail addresses that are created on the fly by a computer program and only used one time.

Comment: The answer then is still no. At least not out of the box. However, It's no big deal to script what I do manually. i.e. Don't try to do it within Exchange, do it with normal AD account scripting methods. The script can be run from whatever software you use.

Answer (score 1):

A Microsoft representative announced on June 16 2020 that they are currently beta testing this functionality for Office 365 and expect the feature to be available to all users by the end of August 2020.

https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273493-office-365-admin/suggestions/18612754-support-for-dynamic-email-aliases-in-office-36