# E-mail addresses with plus sign in MS Exchange

Tags: email, exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Exchange support disposable e-mail addresses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/121289/does-exchange-support-disposable-e-mail-addresses)

Many users like to use e-mail address in the format "[user]+[tag]@[domain]" to facilitate local filtering of incoming messages. The semantics of that is that the message should be delivered to the mailbox belonging to "user"; the user would advertise his/her address with different tags to different potential senders and would then be able to filter incoming messages according to sender (and also to track who got the e-mail address from where).

The question is: is it possible to get MS Exchange (2007) to deliver messages in this format properly? If so, how exactly? Internet searches seem to imply it is not a possibility...

Comment: Duplicate of [Does Exchange support disposable e-mail addresses?](http://serverfault.com/questions/121289/does-exchange-support-disposable-e-mail-addresses)

Comment: I am not sure they are the same. This question is asking for Sub-Addressing [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags], the other question Disposable Email Addresses [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disposable_email_address]. Both features I would love to see implemented in Exchange. I vote that these questions be uncoupled and have their intentions clarified.

Answer (score 2):

Deliver to internal users? No. This is primarily a feature of Google Mail and isn't part of the feature set of Exchange. It may be available via an add-on component but I'm not aware of one.

As for delivering from Exchange users to GMail users, it should work fine with no configuration changes.

Comment: It is not really a feature of GMail, but of most e-mail systems I have ever used. It is pretty much standard for most, if not all, Unix-based mail delivery systems. I would be very surprised if it were not supported at all on Exchange (although it's starting to look like this is indeed the case).

Answer (score 0):

You can add each combination the user could want mail delivered to their AD account. But you can't say [user]+* gets delivered to [user].

Comment: ... and what if you want to integrate a ticketing system that is using the + section for each ticket. Should we hire an army of sysadmins to do this?

Comment: A good sysadmin would write a script to add the relevant transport rule, if you're set on using Exchange.