# Does Exchange support plussed users (e.g. myname+spam@example.com) or a similar mechanism?

Tags: exchange, email

Sendmail supports a feature called 'plussed users'. Once enabled, emails sent to

- `myname+spam@example.com`,
- `myname+sometopic@example.com` and
- `myname+anything@example.com`

are automatically delivered just like mails to `myname@example.com`. There is no need to register or set up these 'plus suffixes'. The user can just use them and set up client-side filtering rules on his own.

Does Exchange support a similar mechanism? If so, how to enable it?

Note that I don't want answers about other means of filtering, e.g. spam/junk filtering, server-side or client-side rules, email aliases/addresses that are configured explicitly and so on.

Comment: What's the purpose of this "feature"?

Comment: For example, if you are active in a forum called 'lolcat', you might use the myname+lolcat@example.com address there. This way, if people use the e-mail link displayed in your forum posts, you can have a client-side filtering rule to make sure that all these mails get flagged/through your spam filter/sorted into a folder/you name it.

Comment: No, but if your name is Jane Doe, and your alias is **jdoe**, you can usually receive mail using either jdoe@example.com or jane.doe@example.com. That's one extra email address anyway. :-)

Comment: @joeqwerty Gmail does it too.  I'm not sure if G. Apps for Business does it though.  I do not think it's really applicable to Exchange use cases, which are much more organizational (official?) in nature.  Mailbox Rules or Clutter would be Exchange features that address the need, IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Exchange 2007 / 2010 doesn't support it, the only way would be to create your own MTA (Mail Transport Agent). Luckily there's (at least) one guy that already did the basics for you.

http://durdle.com/regexcatchall/

> RegExCatchAll is a Transport Agent for Microsoft Exchange 2007 and 2010. It provides email suffix matching based on standard .NET regular expressions and can deliver email to Exchange Mailboxes or external SMTP addresses. It stores its configuration in an XML file which can be updated live without restarting any services. It also includes a “banned alias” list, so you can blacklist any of your previously used suffixes

HTH

Answer (score 8):

No, Exchange doesn't support this. A similar feature (nicknamed "disposable e-mail addresses") was proposed for Exchange 2010, but it didn't make the cut.

Answer (score 2):

I went into a bit of a wiki-hole on this one, based on an off-hand comment that Outlook.com supports this from a [source article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags) for a [linked question](https://serverfault.com/questions/121289/does-exchange-support-disposable-e-mail-addresses) (it doesn't, really).  Outlook.com obviously runs on Exchange at some level, so I simply **had** to satisfy my curiosity.

If you're an Exchange admin, you can create a mail contact for whatever you want at your domain, and have it deliver to the destination of your choosing.  This of course does not equate to the ad-hoc usage of **user**+**subject**@domain.com.

If you're an Outlook.com user, you can apparently create an alias at http://mail.live.com/?rru=createalias, at a rate of up to 5 per year.  This also does not equate to the ad-hoc usage of **user**+**subject**@domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying definitively, but sending to my username "+test@" work (E2k3) email did not come through.  I'm not willing yet to say that it doesn't work at all, but it doesn't work in my environment.

Also a cursory search of the web does not come up with any references.  It may be possible to enable this behavior, but I don't know how.

Comment: Same results here. name+text@domain.com failed to deliver.

Comment: Right, it didn't work for me either, and as I couldn't find any info on the web, I decided to ask here :-)