# How can I map multiple SMTP email addresses to one account in Exhange 2003?

Tags: email, exchange-2003

I mean classes of addresses. I don't want to have to manually add each address. E.g.

1 - [Local-part tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Address_tags): account+[tag]@domain.com, e.g. account+dog@... account+cat@....
2 - A virtual sub-domain: [anyone]@sub.domain.com, e.g. dog@... cat@...

In both cases all emails would be sent to one account, and then on mail retrieval further processing can use the local part account or tag (e.g. dog, cat) as meta-data.

Both of these methods can be implemented in sendmail e.g. using +detail syntax in [virtusertable](http://www.sendmail.org/m4/features.html). Hopefully Exchange offers similar flexibility. I know what I want but the docs aren't helping.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the answer to a [similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/121289/does-exchange-support-disposable-e-mail-addresses) Exchange can't do this.

Note that the similar question talks about pre-generated disposable email addresses, whereas what I want is emails directed to a common inbox by ignoring the tag suffix.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you need to be looking at the recipient policies etc in ESM, but am not overly sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you give examples with real (made up) names so we know what you want to achieve?

Comment: I've added some examples and links to help explain what's possible in other mail servers. Recipient policies (and its help) was where I was lost in before posting here. Thanks for confirming that's the first place one should look.

Answer (score 0):

Extra addresses can be added to a recipient on their "E-Mail Addresses" tab - is this what you mean?

Comment: Thanks, but no. I've edited to clarify - sorry for the poor first attempt!

Comment: @Nick In that case, Kip's answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Shane. I've added more examples of the mapping I'm after.